# wsHttpBinding with username password

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to set `wsHttpBinding` with username / password. 
The problem that I've ran into is how to set username / password?

I've set this:

```
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
      binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

But where is the setting for username / password?

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
  binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
  binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;


  Type contractType = typeof(ITest);
  Type serviceType = typeof(Test);
  Uri httpUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8083/Test2");
  ServiceHost myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceType, httpUri);

  ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
  smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
  myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

  myServiceHost.Open();
```

Code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  [ServiceContract]
  interface ITest
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string Ping();
  }
}



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Test : ITest
  {
    public string Ping()
    {
      return "Pong - it works!";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WCF uses Windows users to authenticate. But you can plugin your own custom validator.

You need to create your class inherited from `UserNamePasswordValidator` and then tell WCF to use it:

```
myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceCredentials>().UserNameAuthentication
.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceCredentials>().UserNameAuthentication
.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new MyCustomValidator();
```

See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636233/wcf-custom-username-and-password-validator-using-a-repository-database-c-sharp) and [official MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Do I have to add something before that code? I am receiving null reference exception on the first line.

Comment: Basically the problem is that this is null: myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceCredentials>().

Comment: Then just add new ServiceCredentials behavior into myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors